# Why do I get 'Expected the reducer to be a function.'?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting my head around redux/react but having issues with my reducer:

```
const reducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state++;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Trying to inject this into my store:

```
const store = createStore(reducer);
```

How can I avoid this error?

[link to codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/2px4zrm3rn)

Comment: hoisting. put your `const reducer = ...` before the store declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the sandbox!

Your "reducer" variable isn't defined when `createStore` is executed.  Either 1) define it before you use it, or 2) define it with a function declaration:

```
function reducer(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state++;

    default:
  return state;
  }
}
```

which causes it to be "hoisted" (See "[Function Declaration Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)").

After that, you'll notice that you get a subsequent error:

> Expected listener to be a function.

on `store.subscribe(App);`.  This is because class declarations *aren't* hoisted (see "[Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)").  So you'll want the class declaration of `App` before `store.subscribe(App);`.

Comment: what an great answer !